# How to share code between activities in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, popupmenu

So I have some popup menu button in some activities. The problem is that in every activity I have to use the same code to initialize popup menu over and over again...

The code for initialization looks like this:

```
var button = FindViewById(Resource.Id.moreButton);

button.Click += (s, arg) =>
{
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, button);
    menu.Inflate(Resource.Menu.PopupMenu);
    menu.Show();

    menu.MenuItemClick += (s1, arg1) =>
    {
        switch (arg1.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString())
        {
            case "Profile":
                StartActivity(typeof(ProfileView));
                break;
            case "Prices":
                StartActivity(typeof(PricesView));
                break;
            case "Terms":
                StartActivity(typeof(TermsView));
                break;
            case "Privacy":
                StartActivity(typeof(PrivacyView));
                break;
        }
    };
};
```

So in every activity that has popup menu button, I have to use this code to make button work.... How could I share this code part through all the activities?

Comment: Refactor into a class/methods that you re-use within each Activity or subclass an Activity, place all your common code there and then use that subclass as the base class for your Activities, or, my preferred way, do not use independent Activities for each of your "screens", use `Fragments`. Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create your own class that extends 'PopupMenu' and then add a method to initialize everything and display it.

```
public class MyPopupMenu : PopupMenu 
{
    //May need to add constructors

    public void display()
    {
        this.Inflate(Resource.Menu.PopupMenu);
        this.Show();

        //May need to change EventArgs to a valid subclass of EventArgs
        this.MenuItemClicked += (object sender, EventArgs arg1) =>
        {
            switch (arg1.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString())
            {
                case "Profile":
                    break;
                case "Prices":
                    break;
                case "Terms":
                    break;
                case "Privacy":
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can shorten your code on each page to:

```
var button = FindViewById(Resource.Id.moreButton);

button.Click += (s, arg) => {
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, button); 
    menu.display();
};
```

Quick disclaimer, I hadn't had a chance to test this. Just my ideas.

Comment: Yeah that looks like a nice workaround, but there is a small problem... in every case I need to call `StartActivity` method to navigate somewhere, but now in `MyPopupClass` I can't do that...

Comment: This may not work then. Could I see your code for where and how you call OnStartActicity?

Comment: I updated my questuon code. Added where I'm calling `StartActivity`

Comment: Could you add an Activity parameter to the constructor of MyPopupMenu? Then you could call activity.startActivity(...). Once again, I apologise that this is untested. My computer is out of commission for the next few days

Comment: That worked fine! I even didn't had to inherit `PopupMenu` class.. Just passing `Activity` to a method is enough in my case

Comment: Glad I could help!